# is JasperReports Library 5.5.2 compatible with JDK 1.6_23?

Tags: jasper-reports, java-7, java-6, netweaver

We are currently using JasperReports Library 4.4.7 with JDK 1.6_23 on SAP NetWeaver 7.3 and we are planing to upgrade to 5.5.2, is it compatible with our environment JDK (1.6_23) since the library is compiled using JDK 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

If the library is compiled using JDK 1.7, it won't run on Java SE 6-compatible environment. You would need to compile it (and jar) yourself -- I don't know the library, but it's likely to fail. Perhaps they switched to Java 7 compilation to use Java 7 features.

You may also "downgrade" the compiled byte code of the library to be Java 6 compliant -- see [Compiling Java 7 to Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661980/compiling-java-7-to-java-6) (I have no experience with that either).